# Golang letsencrypt как прикрепить ssl для https?

Tags: golang

```
    r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/api/user/files/{user_id}/{file_id}", request.DeleteFile).Methods("DELETE")
  r.HandleFunc("/api/user/files", request.UploadFile).Methods("POST")
  r.HandleFunc("/api/user/files/{user_id}/{file_id}", request.DownloadFile).Methods("GET")
  err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080",
    "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/nearbywork.ru/cert1.pem",
    "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/nearbywork.ru/privkey1.pem", r)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }
```

Без TLS запускается и слушает порт. Если запускать TLS просто вхолостую, исполняется и завершается без ошибок. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чём проблема. Если честно, то она вообще не описана. Судя по Вашему коду всё должно работать.

Comment: Проблема была в том что 8080 не поддерживает https

Comment: Смею Вас заверить, что HTTPS может слушать на любом порту. Если клиент делает HTTPS запрос, то проблем не будет.

Comment: Проблема в том что демон слушающий порт не запускался. И ошибок никаких, а на 8443 все заработало.